# Callback function not executing Delphi

Tags: delphi, callback

I have a method in my com object that is implemented as a callback ad defined below:

```
FCallBackMethod: IDispatch;
```

To trigger the callback i call the following function

```
procedure TCallback.SignalCallbackAsString(const AJSonMessage: String);
var Args : array[0..0] of TVariantArg;
begin
  Args[0] := StrToVariantArg(AJSonMessage);
  Logger.Trace('Signaling callback ' + AJSonMessage);
  InvokeMethod(FCallBackMethod, Args);
  SysFreeString(Args[0].bstrVal);
end;
```

InvokeMethod is defined as :

```
procedure InvokeMethod(Method: IDispatch; pArgs: array of TVariantArg);
var
  DispParams: TDispParams;
  InvKind: Integer;
  ArgCount: Integer;
begin
  if VarIsNull(Method) or VarIsEmpty(Method) or VarIsClear(Method) then
      Exit;

    FillChar(DispParams, sizeof(DispParams), 0);

    ArgCount := High(pArgs) - Low(pArgs) + 1;

    FillChar(DispParams, sizeof(DispParams), 0);
    InvKind := DISPATCH_METHOD;

    DispParams.rgvarg := PVariantArgList(@pArgs);
    DispParams.cArgs := ArgCount;

    Method.Invoke(0, GUID_NULL, 0, InvKind, DispParams, nil, nil, nil);
end;
```

If i add a button to the main form an call it using `Callback.SignalCallbackAsString(TCPMessageRead);` 
it all works as expected.

However, when i trigger it from a thread i doesn't work. I figured it was a problem executing it from a separate thread so i passed it on to the main thread by sending TCPMessageRead using "SendMessage". Everything is triggering as expected but the callback doesn't reach the other application.

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you tell us more about the whole architecture and how the threading is handled. What is the COM object? It's a COM server? In-proc, out-of-proc? What about the threading model of the COM server? Is COM initialized? Who creates the thread? The COM server or the COM client? As it stands I'm finding it a little hard to work out exactly what is going on here.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response David. I actually solved it by calling the callback from a Synchronize method.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you call `CoInitialize(nil);` once for each thread you start, prior to accessing COM objects, by preference in the first code the thread will run.